# Shared library not loaded on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, shared-libraries

I would like to use [MediaInfo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/) library in my application. It is not easy to compile it for Android but I found an already compiled binary version [here](https://github.com/OLEG4120/MediaInfoCLI-android).

I use QtCreator to develop my application and build the installation APK. On Windows everything runs fine. But if I try it on Android, I first get this error when starting the application:

> D/dalvikvm( 3296): Trying to load lib/data/app-lib/org.qtproject.muzika-2/libmediainfo.so 0xb3d087b0
>
> E/linker ( 3296): "libmediainfo.so": ignoring 2-entry DT_PREINIT_ARRAY in shared library!
>
> D/dalvikvm( 3296): Added shared lib/data/app-lib/org.qtproject.muzika-2/libmediainfo.so 0xb3d087b0
>
> D/dalvikvm( 3296): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.muzika-2/libmediainfo.so 0xb3d087b0, skipping init

But at least it seems the library was found an loaded. But if I try to actually use it, I get always this output:

> D/libMuzika.so( 3296): (null):0 ((null)): "Unable to load libmediainfo.so"

I do believe the error message comes from the [header file of this library](https://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/code/HEAD/tree/MediaInfoLib/trunk/Source/MediaInfoDLL/MediaInfoDLL.h#l544). For some reason the library is not loaded. But I'm not able to figure out why.

How can I find out what is the problem?

Comment: There is one nice and reliable way to check if DSO was loaded or not. Go to device shell, then find PID of  your application (`ps` and `grep`), then check address space of your process with `cat /proc/{pid}/maps`.

Comment: a974a000-a9750000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0I tried that and the library seems to be loaded. This is the output from cat /proc/... :
a9445000-a973a000 r-xp 00000000 1f:01 9406       /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.muzika-1/libmediainfo.so
a973a000-a9744000 r--p 002f4000 1f:01 9406       /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.muzika-1/libmediainfo.so
a9744000-a974a000 rw-p 002fe000 1f:01 9406       /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.muzika-1/libmediainfo.so
a974a000-a9750000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

Comment: Nice. And now post your code that tries to use that library and prints `D/libMuzika.so( 3296): (null):0 ((null)): "Unable to load libmediainfo.so"`.

Comment: Where the error (most likely) comes from is the header file from my original post. If you click on the link, it points directly to the line where I think it is defined. Then in my code I include this header file, create a handle `MediaInfo = MI;` and call some function of the library, for example `out = MI.Inform().c_str();` The text _"Unable to load libmediainfo.so"_ is what the function returns.

Comment: I did some more tests and debugging an I found out the error comes from these lines:    `#define MEDIAINFO_ASSIGN(_Name,_Name2) \
    MediaInfo_##_Name=(MEDIAINFO_##_Name)dlsym(MediaInfo_Module, "MediaInfo" MEDIAINFO_Ansi "_" _Name2); \
    if (MediaInfo_##_Name==NULL) Errors++;`  It is in the header file I referenced here before. What does this construction do? Why it isn't working and how do I change it to work on Android?

Comment: In few words this construction looks for some function in your library, and probably can not find it. You can use `dlerror()` immediately after this macro to obtain description of actual error.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the command. In fact it calls for example this: `MediaInfo_Inform=(MEDIAINFO_Inform)dlsym(MediaInfo_Module, "MediaInfo_Inform");`  The error I get is this: **undefined symbol: MediaInfo_Inform**. It seems the library is loaded but it fails to find the functions inside of it. Do you have any idea what can I check further?

Comment: You can use `readelf` to check names of dynamic symbols that exist in your  `libmediainfo.so`. Try something like `$ readelf --wide --dyn-syms libmediainfo.so`. Then you can compare existing symbols names with requested.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful advices. It seems the library is missing the functions I'm looking for. I don't understand it as it seems to be the correct library. Anyway I will try to compile it myself.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is a hack.

1.Download Mediainfo app from [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mediainfo.android.app&hl=en).

2.Open APK file with WinZip.

3.Extract files in libs folder.

4.Select libmediainfo.so base on your architecture.

5.Use this libs instead of [this](https://github.com/OLEG4120/MediaInfoCLI-android).

This lib work for me.

Maybe help.